# Difference between a Repository Implementation using ObjectContext vs DbContext on EF 4.1

Tags: repository-pattern, entity-framework-4.1, self-tracking-entities

What could be the better implementation for STE, I heard about that DbContext is the simplest way to implement a Repo with EF, personally I take advantage of the EntityState, but there is any member on ObjectContext that could deliver more functionallity for my CRUD operations using Repo? at today I'm using a GenericRepository like this one :

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal DbContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWithRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return dbSet.SqlQuery(query, parameters).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I forgot to mention that also I'm using Unity, so the calls to Repository are like this way :

```
[Dependency]
        public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

        public List<Case> GetAll()
        {
            using (var context = Container.Resolve<ClaimEntities>())
            {
                var qry = (from c in context.Cases
                           select c).ToList();
                return qry;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self tracking entities are feature of ObjectContext - they are [not supported in DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696165%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). If you want STEs you need to swap to ObjectContext API and use STEs T4 template to generate entities instead of your current POCOs.